# Editing midi events

Tags: java, midi, javasound, javax.sound.midi

I’m attempting to editing the pitch of existing midi notes in a sequence by moving the graphical notes (rectangles) in a piano roll editor up or down.  Reading over the APIs and online documents, it doesn’t get very specific on how to edit existing notes.  From the best I can tell, I need to use the setMessage() method to overwrite the existing ShortMessage.  Here’s what I’ve got right now:

```
public void changePitch(int pitchUpOrDown) {
    MidiMessage message =  this.getMessage();
    message.setMessage(___?, ____?, ____? + pitchUpOrDown, ____?);
}
```

I’m calling changePitch() from a JPanel by mouse-dragging a note, and I’m sending either +1 or –1 as the increment by which the pitch will be adjusted.  What I can’t find is the values that need to go in the other four blank parameters of the setMessage() call.  Logically, I want to keep the existing values for command, channel and timestamp, but how do I access these existing values so that I can put them in the blanks?  I’ve tried things like message.command, or message[0], etc. but they don’t work.  Also, in the documentation, the args for set Message are shown as (byte[] data, int length).  The explanation for these args is really vague, and they definitely don’t match the args I used to create the ShortMessage in the first place.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `MidiMessage` down to `ShortMessage` and then you can get the pitch and velocity as data1 and data2:

```
if (message instanceof ShortMessage) {
    ShortMessage shortMessage = (ShortMessage) message;

    if(shortMessage.getCommand() == ShortMessage.NOTE_ON) {
        int channel = shortMessage.getChannel();
        int pitch = shortMessage.getData1();
        int vel = shortMessage.getData2();
        if(vel > 0) {
            shortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, channel, pitch + pitchUpOrDown, vel);
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to change the next NOTE_OFF message as well. This will either be a shortMessage with a NOTE_OFF command, or a NOTE_ON command with a velocity of 0.

Comment: Thank you! That totally worked! But you're right about the NOTE-OFF. These edited notes don't turn off anymore. But how do I find the correct NOTE_OFF message in the Vector of notes in order to edit it?

Comment: If they were ordered by timestamp, then it would be the next NOTE_OFF message with the same pitch and channel.

Comment: Would I find the NOTE_OFF message by trying to access it within the Vector (which I believe is the track)? Or would that be some kind of if statement, like, "if note is such and such pitch and channel and has command of NOTE_OFF and is timestamped later than_______"? This is where the documentation is really vague.  They tell you how to create a message, but there is very little detail in the API about how to access the messages once they're created. I've been printing out examples and reading books and scouring the API.

Comment: @KyleWalker You need to iterate over the track checking each note with an if statement. Another way is to create the notes in a custom data structure that's easier to edit, and recreate the sequence every time it's needed.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but this is exactly where I'm confused. How do you iterate over a track? It doesn't have a variable assigned to it (unless "track" is the variable), so how do I reference it? Thanks SO much for your patience.

Comment: @KyleWalker Do you have a track object? Then it's `for(int i = 0; i < track.size(); i++) track.get(i)`